# SAS: macro send email if exist

Tags: email, sas

I try build little system which will verify that attachment exist (from 4 sources) and if exists - send this attachments with email.
If exist one - then send it.
I found interesting code but I have problem with little verify four files and gluing variable with path to them.

```
%LET ATTACH1=%STR(C:\XXX\YYYY\ZZZZZ\XYZ_1_&calosc..csv);
%LET ATTACH2=%STR(C:\XXX\YYYY\ZZZZZ\XYZ_2_&calosc..csv);
%LET ATTACH3=%STR(C:\XXX\YYYY\ZZZZZ\XYZ_3_&calosc..csv);
%LET ATTACH4=%STR(C:\XXX\YYYY\ZZZZZ\XYZ_4_&calosc..csv);

%MACRO FINDMYFILE;
%LET ZALACZNIKI = ;
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH1)) %THEN &ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI || &ATTACH1 || ' ';
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH2)) %THEN &ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI || &ATTACH2 || ' ';
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH3)) %THEN &ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI || &ATTACH3 || ' ';
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH4)) %THEN &ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI || &ATTACH4 || ' ';
%PUT &ZALACZNIKI;

 %IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH1)) OR %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH2)) OR %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH3)) OR %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH4)) %THEN 
    %DO;
         FILENAME OUTBOX EMAIL
         FROM = ("XX SYSTEM REPORT <noreply@systemaccount>")
         TO = ("xzy.yzx@email.com")
         CC = ("xzy.yzx@email.com")
         REPLYTO = ("xzy.yzx@email.com")
         SUBJECT = (" testowy ")
         ATTACH = ("&ZALACZNIKI.");
         DATA _NULL_;
         FILE OUTBOX;
         PUT "Hello,";
         PUT ;
         PUT %SYSFUNC(COMPBL(
         "This is an example email."));
         PUT ;
         PUT %SYSFUNC(COMPBL(
        "By using COMPBL we remove extra blanks from our text."));
         PUT %SYSFUNC(COMPBL(
        "There is no separation with this email line."));
         RUN;
         FILENAME OUTBOX CLEAR;
    %END;
 %ELSE %PUT NOTE: FILE DOES NOT EXIST AND NO EMAIL WILL BE SENT.;
%MEND FINDMYFILE;
%FINDMYFILE;
```

Thank for help :)

Comment: Can you share what isn't working here? Any error codes or warnings?

Comment: If you are using a data step already why not just use the data step to do the testing?  You can use email directives to attach the files  that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things here:

```
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH4)) %THEN &ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI || &ATTACH4 || ' ';
```

You need to use %LET to reassign a macro variable, if that's your intention, and the concatenation operators are not required, but you may need double-quotes around the filename:

```
%IF %SYSFUNC(FILEEXIST(&ATTACH4)) %THEN %LET ZALACZNIKI = &ZALACZNIKI. "&ATTACH4.";
```

When you come to use the macro variable, you probably won't need the quotes, otherwise you'll get:

> ""file1" "file2" "file3""

So just do this:

```
ATTACH = (&ZALACZNIKI.);
```

Experiment with this code to learn how it works:

```
%let file1 = C:\temp;
%let file2 = C:\temp2;

%let z = ;

%let z = &z. "&file1.";
%let z = &z. "&file2.";

%put &z;
```